# My header i not cover

Tags: html, css, materialize

My problem is that my header is not covering the navbar.
I'm using materialize.

```
<div class="header">
  <img src="img/header.png" />
</div>
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper teal darken-3">
    <a href="#!" class="brand-logo"><img src="img/brandlogo" alt="NobleStudios" /></a>
    <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="members.php">Members</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
  <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="members.php">Members</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what your problem is?

Comment: Did not understand your question. Please explain a little more.

Comment: *.. is not cover :D

Comment: Could you explain a little bit better what is the issue? It seems that you want your header component to cover your navbar, but I'm not sure exactly what do you mean by that. Could you maybe provide an example that shows how it should look?

Answer (score 0):

Defined properties in `.header class` like so.

```css
            .header {
              padding: 20px;
              background: black;
              color: white;
             }
```

```html
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
            <body>
            <div class="header">
            <img src="img/header.png"></img>
            <span>Header Content</span>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar -->
            <nav>
              <div class="nav-wrapper teal darken-3">
                <a href="#!" class="brand-logo"><img src="img/brandlogo" alt="NobleStudios"></img></a>
                <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                  <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="members.php">Members</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                  <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
            
            <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
              <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="members.php">Members</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
            </ul>
            
            </body>
```